# Spark Dataframe has duplicated values in all rows when adding column with random double

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to add a new column to dataframe. The new column contains random double value. The problem is duplicated values in the new column for all rows in DataFrame. I'm using scala.util.Random class for generating.

I've tried to simply add a new column to dataframe, like it was adviced in similar posts. I have tried to change DataFrame to Dataset and add column. There is a working method - collect data on driver and add to List of tuple new element containing random double, but it's a bad solution for big amounts of data, so I can't use this solution.

Spark Version 2.2.0, I've used spark-shell for implementation

```
List(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3))
.toDF("str", "digit")
.withColumn("random", lit(scala.util.Random.nextDouble))
.show(10)
```

Here are results
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ijV5.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate random double values instead of using **`withColumn`** specify **`scala.util.Random`** in your List.

**Ex:**

```
val rnd_df=List(("1",9,Some(scala.util.Random.nextDouble)),
                ("1",9,Some(scala.util.Random.nextDouble)))
          .toDF("str","digit","random")
rnd_df.show(false)
```

**`Result:`**

```
+---+-----+------------------+
|str|digit|random            |
+---+-----+------------------+
|1  |9    |0.7370861605665576|
|1  |9    |0.5691922799783725|
+---+-----+------------------+
```

**UPDATE:**

Use **`rand()`** in `withColumn` function

```
List(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3))
.toDF("str", "digit")
.withColumn("random", lit(rand()))
.show(10)
```

**`Result:`**

```
+---+-----+-------------------+
|str|digit|             random|
+---+-----+-------------------+
|  a|    1| 0.5952030024781159|
|  b|    2| 0.9646080878588672|
|  c|    3|0.21797137458332738|
+---+-----+-------------------+
```

Comment: No, no, I don't need list, it's just for example. I'm reading hive table, or somehow reading ORC content, so List is just for example